# trying to get access to data on a website using excel VBA and I need to be able to click a button

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use VBA to access data off the web from excel. When I try to go to the website it is redirected to another website which is a banner warning and there is a big button that says "OK" that I need VBA to automatically press. There is a pause in the code using msgbox because the user needs to enter security card clearance which then automatically takes you to the site and then the code starts again when you click the OK on the msgbox as if it is starting at the redirected website (banner warning site).

This is my code for it. I can pull up everything until after the msgbox function and everything after that is not working. any help would be fantastic

```
Sub GetTable()
Dim ieApp As InternetExplorer
Dim ieDoc As Object
Dim ieTable As Object
Dim clip As DataObject
Set ieApp = New InternetExplorer
ieApp.Visible = True
ieApp.Navigate "***Website URL***"
MsgBox "Click OK After you fill out Card Security Certificate!"
Set ieDoc = ieApp.Document

Set elements = ieDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")

For Each element In elements
    If element.Name = "OK" Then
        element.Click
    End If
Next element

Set elements = Nothing
```

Comment: Please show the relevant HTML and share the URL if possible. And what does not working mean? Do you select the right element? And have you tried element.focus: element.Click?

Comment: By not working I mean that it is not reading anything after the msgbox pops up and the first code after it is popping up on the debugger as not being read. I cannot share the website or the HTML for security reasons I am sorry if you cannot help without it. I might be able to send the HTML for just the button portion of the site.

Comment: Try setting the focus to the button, see this tip .. http://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.com/2018/02/vba-ie-createevent-and-dispatchevent-to.html#focusTip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out the problem was because I was not using internetexplorermedium. I then just used ready state instead of using the message box as a pause button which made the program much more efficient. Thanks for all the help